# check unmanaged folder diverse from which git commit

Tags: git, diff

Say we have a folder `project_A` which is managed by git.

And say we know that another folder `project_A_fork`, which is not managed by git, diverse/fork from certain commit of `project_A` commit tree history.

For `project_A_fork`, another author had modified a few content, and the `project_A` were upgraded by the public community commits meanwhile.

So, how can we know which commit point the `project_A_fork` start to diverse/fork from `project_A`.

Just for a non-optimal approach:

Iterate all the commit in `project_A`'s commit history and statistics the `diff amount` (num of addition and deletion) for `project_A_fork` compare to each commit folder status. And choose the commit that the `diff amount` is the most smallest one.

Does anyone has a better solution?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a Git repo `project_A`. At some point someone copied the content into `project_A_fork` and made a bunch of changes. Meanwhile, more commits were made to `project_A`. Now you want to find out what commit `project_A` was at when the copy was done?

Comment: Why is the fork not also a git repo? How do you not know what commit it's from, or what's changed since that point?

Comment: Also, why do you need to know this? Perhaps it can be avoided.

Comment: Some other author forked from `project_A` to `project_A_fork` at certain commit, and delete the `.git` folder of `project_A_fork`, then this author modifies some content of `project_A_fork` folder.

Comment: @myme5261314 Did they fork the project on Github? If so then the Github network graph for your project will tell you when they forked. https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>/network

Answer (score 1):

You can't really know what commit `project_A_fork` was copied from if it's been modified, but there are some common tells to narrow the search.

Contributors rarely touch things like version numbers, README files, or change logs. First thing I'd look for is a version number and diff based on that. Then I'd look for README files, change logs, and other administrative files they're unlikely to touch and see if they match a particular commit. This will bound your search for a match.

Usually people who aren't using version control will be working from a source release, so I'd compare only releases of the project to see which one came closest.

Comment: Thanks, @Schwern. Actually when you can only get an unmanaged and modified directory just like `project_A_fork`, I think the only valid approach to check is to compare against a bunch of commit/release.

Comment: Just for the problem I'm facing, the author also uses version control, but he just do what as I said, fork `project_A` to `project_A_fork`, remove `.git` directory, modified some content of `project_A_fork` and use it as a sub-directory of `project_B`. That makes it hard to merge `project_A_fork` with the current latest master or release of `project_A`, and leads vast amount of unsolved issues remained in `project_A_fork`.

Comment: Also, check the created/last updated dates on the files in `project_A_fork`. That'll narrow things down too.

Comment: @myme5261314 Ask that they leave the `.git` directory alone or look into [submodules instead](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).